# Confidence interval of $p$ based on two random variables

Tags: statistics, confidence-interval

Let $f(x;p) = p\cdot f_{X_1}(x) + (1-p)\cdot f_{X_2}(x)$ where $X_1 \sim N(1,1)$ and $X_2 \sim N(0,1)$. Based on a sample of size $n = 1$ from $f(x;p)$, derive a one-sided lower $100\lambda\%$ confidence limit of $p$

I tried to find pdf of $f(x;p)$ to see if it belongs to any regular distribution but I failed. I kinda don't know any other way to approach this problem.

Comment: Sum of two Normal random variables is normal with $N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ where $\mu = p\times 1 + (1-p) \times 1 = 1$ (expectation) and $\sigma^2 = p^2 var(X_1) + (1-p)^2 var(X_2) + 2(p-1)(p)cov(X_1, X_2)$ (variance).  See for example [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_normally_distributed_random_variables)

Comment: Also for the above to hold you have to assume that the random variables are jointly normal. For example If $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent then they are jointly normal.

Comment: @user90793 : This doesn't involve a sum of two normally distributed random variables.  What is being summed is not the random variables, but scalar multiples of the densities.  That gives you a bimodal density that is certainly not normal. $\qquad$

Comment: You are right, my mistake.

Comment: So your null hypothesis is $p=p_0$ and your alternative hypothesis is $p<p_0$? That means that your alternative hypothesis is supported if $X$ is closer to zero than to 1. Specifically under the assumption $p=p_0$ and the observation $X=x$ the probability that $X$ would be less than or equal to $x$ is $p_0\Phi(x-1)+(1-p_0)\Phi(x)$. So you would reject the null hypothesis with $100(1-\alpha)\%$ confidence provided $x$ is so small that $p_0\Phi(x-1)+(1-p_0)\Phi(x)<\alpha$.

Comment: If you get this then I think you should be able to construct the confidence interval (hypothesis testing and confidence interval construction are in some sense the same).